# C# SqlClient - Unable to connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server

We have a C# app running on a server that connects to a different server running SQL Server 2008.  Both machines run Windows Server 2008 R2.

When the application runs we get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it.)

The code is:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<redacted IP>\<redacted instance name>;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=<redacted>;User ID=sa;Password=<redacted>;"))    
{
    connection.Open();
```

Interestingly, running the following in Powershell works fine:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=<redacted IP>\<redacted instance name>;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=<redacted>;User ID=sa;Password=<redacted>;");
$conn.Open()
```

I can only assume that there's some sort of ACL issue going on but I can find no info on it.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server

Comment: stupid question maybe but that powershell script,  on which machine do run it?

Comment: the same one running the application.

Comment: Mitch, that's a pretty general connectivity issues article and does not address my issue.  I can connect using the SqlClient from Powershell but not from my app.

Comment: @RichardPayne Powershell is .NET, is uses the same ADO.NET classes. Besides the message clearly says that the *server* refused the connection, which means you are using the wrong port or protocol - why did you specify `Network Library=DBMSSOCN;` in the connection string? If you use an IP address ADO.NET will use TCP/IP.

Comment: Get rid of Network Library=DBMSSOCN

Comment: Here you can read about similar issue: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ajaykumarks/2010/08/25/connectivity-to-sql-server-fails-when-network-library-dbmssocn-is-used-in-addtion-to-having-a-tcp-alias/

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't remember exactly why we added the network library; it was some time ago.  I do remember that it was the only way we could get the connection to work back then.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that Powershell is .Net.   That's why it's odd that the SqlClient using the same connection string works in PS but not in my app.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the connection string is correct. In case you are working on Visual Studio, I suggest you use the Servers and Data Connections from the Server Explorer.

Once you have established a connection from there to your target SQL you can right click on it (again from the Server Explorer -> Data Connections) and select properties, there you can find the connection string you need need only with redacted password which you will have to replace.

Make sure to check if the firewall settings in server side allow inbound connections to the database (probably it will be set already).

Check if your SQL Server to accept remote connections.

> - Start > All Programs > SQL Server 2008 > Configuration Tools > SQL    Server Surface Area Configuration
> - Click on Surface Area Configuration    for Services and Connections
> - Select the instance that is having a problem > Database Engine > Remote Connections
> - Enable local and remote connections
> - Restart instance

Finally enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration

When two or more SQL Servers are connected across network they do all communication using TCP/IP. The default port of SQL Server installation is 1433. This port can be changed through SQL Server Configuration Manager. TCP/IP should be enabled for SQL Server to be connected.

> - Go to All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 >> Configuration    Tools >> SQL Server Configuration Manager >> Select TCP/IP
> - Right Click on TCP/IP >> Click on Enable

Best of luck with your progress and feel free to contact me for additional information or the current solution didn't work!

Comment: As stated, I can connect to the server fine using the .Net SqlClient from Powershell.  I can't connect using SqlClient from my C# app.  Both running on the same system.